# Running Teststack.White automation on virtual machine

Tags: c#, excel, white-framework

I am having an issue with running white automation suite on a virtual machine. I have followed the steps mentioned on https://teststackwhite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/AdvancedTopics/ContinuousIntegration/ to download TightVNC and run the suite using it, but still, I am getting the same issue. When I am executing the test, it launches the application but then it does nothing. I am suspecting if it has something to do with the mouse and keyboard connection as white uses the mouse and keyboard interaction. Let me know if someone has experienced the same issue before.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the solution myself. So there were a couple of issues:

1. Don't run your application in admin mode.
2. I was trying to run the automation using gitlab-runner. By default,
   gitlab configure the job using window service. Using the window
   service in an interactive way is the way people suggest but it was
   not working for me. So I invoke it directly using the command, now
   it runs in a command prompt and picks the jobs from the gitlab.

I'll be writing a whole blog on configuring TestStack.White and running the automation from gitlab-runner. Will update the link here once it's done.